# Dynamic variable not working in C# with Json.Net

Tags: c#, json.net

Can anyone tell me why I get an error when trying to output"dJson2.Type" in the code below?

```
    string Json1= @"[{'Id':1, 'FirstName':'John', 'LastName':'Smith'}, {'Id':2, 'FirstName':'Jane', 'LastName':'Doe'}]";
    dynamic dJson1= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Json1);
    Console.WriteLine(dJson1.GetType());
    Console.WriteLine(dJson1.Type);

    string Json2 = @"{'Id':1, 'FirstName':'John', 'LastName':'Smith'}";
    dynamic dJson2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Json2);
    Console.WriteLine(dJson2.GetType());
    Console.WriteLine(dJson2.Type);
```

The program dies on the Console.WriteLine(dJson2.Type) statement.  The output of the program is...

```
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray
Array
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject
(should say Object here, I think)
```

Inspecting the local variables, dJson2 has a "Type" property with value "Object".

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Yeah, the error message should tell you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: `The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Console.WriteLine(string, params object[])'`

Comment: I'm taking a shot in the dark here - I think in the first example the compiler is smart enough to figure out it's an array. But in the second example it's looking for a property called `Type`, and it doesn't exist. Borrowing your code, as soon as I explicitly put in a property called `Type` in your JSON string, it compiled as expected.

Comment: In answer to Stanley/Harvey.  The error actually doesn't help much.  The problem is that the Type property if dJson2 is coming back with a null value.  You can, for instance, add "var jType = dJson2.Type" in the code and you will find that jType is null.

Comment: In response to Kennedy: I think you are onto something, but your answer isn't what I'm looking for.  I'm trying to get the type that Json.Net thinks the parsed object is; I'm not looking for an element in the json string.  But I think that might be what the dynamic stuff is doing.  If I cast dJson2 to a JObject it works.

Comment: I just tried creating a class with a single string property, and instantiated it dynamically (dynamic instance = new MyObject{ };) - forwent Json.Net to be more explicit. I printed out `instance.Type` and got a more concrete error message: `does not contain a definition for 'Type'`. My guess is my hunch was likely close to the bullseye. For your particular instance *with* Json.NET, because it does show `Object` if you hit a breakpoint, I'm going to hazard a guess that you've successfuly uncovered a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because JObject behaves similarly as System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject. Try to change your example to:

```
  string Json2 = @"{'Id':1, 'FirstName':'John', 'LastName':'Smith'}";
  dynamic dJson2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Json2);
  dJson2.Type = "mynewfield";
  Console.WriteLine(dJson2.GetType());
  Console.WriteLine(dJson2.Type);
```

If you want to get property of underlying type you need to cast it (to JToken or JObject), otherwise requested property will be searched in 
`IDictionary<string, JToken>` that JObject implements.

This example may help:

```
  dynamic oobj = new JObject();
  oobj.Type = "TEST";
  Console.WriteLine(oobj.Type);
  Console.WriteLine(((JObject)oobj).Type);
```

Comment: Huh.  Makes sense, though I'm not sure the behavior is what I like or what I would expect.  It's weird that it works for JArray but not JObject.  Anyway, a cast definitely works.  What I ended out doing was a switch on dJson2.GetType(), casting to the actual type, then moving on.  This behaves as expected, if somewhat verbose....  Thanks for explaining, DolphinSX.